# If $n \gt 7\,\,$, then prove that $C^{n-1}_3+ C^{n-1}_4 \gt C^{n}_3$ .

Tags: combinations

I am stuck on the following problem that says ;

> If $n \gt 7\,\,$, then prove that $C^{n-1}_3+ C^{n-1}_4 \gt C^{n}_3, \,\, \text{where}\,\, n\in \mathbb{N} $ and $\,\,C^n_r=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

My try: For  $n \gt 7\,\,$, we check if the statement $P(n): C^{n-1}_3+ C^{n-1}_4 - C^{n}_3 \gt 0\,\,$ is true.

For $n=8$, we see $\,\,P(8): C^7_3+C^7_4-C^8_3 \\ \qquad= \dots\\ \qquad=\frac{8!}{3!.4!}\times \frac{1}{20} 
\gt 0$.

Similarly, for $n=9,10,\dots$ we can check the veracity of the statement.

Now suppose for $n=m$, the statement is true. That means, $P(m): C^{m-1}_3+ C^{m-1}_4 - C^{m}_3 \gt 0\,\,$. Now , I want to prove the statement is true for $n=m+1$.

Now, $P(m+1): C^{m}_3+ C^{m}_4 - C^{m+1}_3 \\ \qquad \qquad= C^{m+1}_4-C^{m+1}_3$ .

Now, I am stuck. Please show me the right direction.

Comment: If you wish to type ${}^nC_r$, you can do so with the code `{}^nC_r`

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks a lot. I was trying to do that but could not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule), $C^{n-1}_3+ C^{n-1}_4 = C^{n}_4\gt C^{n}_3$, since the binomial coefficients in the first half of a row in Pascal's triangle are increasing and $n>7$.

Explicitly,
$$
\frac{C^{n}_4}{C^{n}_3} = \frac{n-3}{4} > \frac{7-3}{4} = 1 
$$